# Objects attribute value is different at end of for-loop vs after loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I want to add one defaultName with a specific `label`, for each name in `name` into `allNameObject`'s "datasets" array.
I instead get the last looped "name" ("Name_5") as the `label` for each `defaultName`.
I'm creating objects for Chart.js so I can't change that.
I have read up on "circular reference" but I can't find if this is that or how to solve it.

```js
var allNameObject = { data: { datasets: [] } }
var defaultName = { label: '' }
var names = ["Name_0", "Name_1", "Name_2", "Name_3", "Name_4", "Name_5"]

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  allNameObject.data.datasets.push(defaultName)
  allNameObject.data.datasets[i].label = names[i]

  console.log(allNameObject.data.datasets[i].label)
  // this correctly outputs "Name_i"
}

console.log(allNameObject.data.datasets[0].label)
// wanted output: "Name_0" || actual output: "Name_5"
console.log(allNameObject.data.datasets[1].label)
// wanted output: "Name_1" || actual output: "Name_5"
console.log(allNameObject.data.datasets[2].label)
// wanted output: "Name_2" || actual output: "Name_5"
console.log(allNameObject.data.datasets[3].label)
// wanted output: "Name_3" || actual output: "Name_5"
console.log(allNameObject.data.datasets[4].label)
// wanted output: "Name_4" || actual output: "Name_5"
console.log(allNameObject.data.datasets[5].label)
// wanted output: "Name_5" || actual output: "Name_5"
```

Comment: You're adding *the same* object `defaultName` every time. So, any time you change it, it changes everywhere. Move the line `var defaultName = { label: '' }` inside the loop to create separate distinct objects.

Comment: Aaaaaahhh! Of course! Thanks a lot @VLAZ !

Answer (score 0):

Solved by [VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) in the comments.
The SAME object (`defaultName.label`) was changed every time. Because I did not create new objects it was just the same object overwriting label every time.

> You're adding the same object defaultName every time. So, any time you
> change it, it changes everywhere. Move the line var defaultName = {
> label: '' } inside the loop to create separate distinct objects. –
> [VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz)

```js
var allNameObject = { data: { datasets: [] } }
var names = ["Name_0", "Name_1", "Name_2", "Name_3", "Name_4", "Name_5"]

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  var defaultName = { label: '' }
  allNameObject.data.datasets.push(defaultName)
  allNameObject.data.datasets[i].label = names[i]

  console.log(allNameObject.data.datasets[i].label)
  // this correctly outputs "Name_i"
}

console.log(allNameObject.data.datasets[0].label)
// wanted output: "Name_0" || actual output: "Name_5"
console.log(allNameObject.data.datasets[1].label)
// wanted output: "Name_1" || actual output: "Name_5"
console.log(allNameObject.data.datasets[2].label)
// wanted output: "Name_2" || actual output: "Name_5"
console.log(allNameObject.data.datasets[3].label)
// wanted output: "Name_3" || actual output: "Name_5"
console.log(allNameObject.data.datasets[4].label)
// wanted output: "Name_4" || actual output: "Name_5"
console.log(allNameObject.data.datasets[5].label)
// wanted output: "Name_5" || actual output: "Name_5"
```